# How to Set TortoiseHG on Mac to diff with 2 parents?

Tags: macos, mercurial, tortoisehg, kdiff3

Here is my settings file:

```
[extensions]
hgext.extdiff =

[extdiff]
cmd.kdiff3 = /Applications/kdiff3.app/Contents/MacOS/kdiff3

[tortoisehg]
vdiff = kdiff3

[ui]
merge = kdiff3

[merge-tools]
kdiff3.executable = /Applications/kdiff3.app/Contents/MacOS/kdiff3
kdiff3.args = $base $local $other -o $output
kdiff3.priority = 1
```

On merge files, when I press `Cmd + D`, it's showing only 2 way diff with the local parent, even if the `List Options` is set to `Changed by This Commit`. In Windows, when I press `Ctrl + D`, its showing 3-way diff with 2 parents even if I didnt change anything on the settings.

How can I set TortoiseHG on Mac to show 3-way diff on merge files when I press `Cmd + D`? I'm using TortoiseHG 3.9.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some [readthedocs quotes](http://tortoisehg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common.html)

> In TortoiseHg 1.0, the visual (external) diff infrastructure was
>   refactored. The new system uses tool descriptions in mergetools.rc to
>   detect most common diff tools on your computer (including KDiff3,
>   which ships in our installer) and select the best available tool.

Since **1.0**, dude!!! ExtDiff isn't mandatory for any merge|diff tool(even custom, while kdiff3 is shipped with THG)

> The visual diff system **will use any existing extdiff** configuration
>   it finds. Since **extdiff did not support three way diff arguments
>   until very recently and still does not support label arguments**, you
>   will likely have a **better experience by disabling or deleting any
>   extdiff configuration** you may have.

Not mutilated by hand default KDiff3 config (from `hgrc.d\MergeTools.rc` in Windows) do **all tasks** properly

```
kdiff3.args=--auto --L1 base --L2 parent1 --L3 parent2 $base $local $other -o $output
kdiff3.regkey=Software\KDiff3
kdiff3.regkeyalt=Software\Wow6432Node\KDiff3
kdiff3.regappend=\kdiff3.exe
kdiff3.fixeol=False
kdiff3.premerge=False
kdiff3.gui=True
kdiff3.priority=-3
kdiff3.diffargs=--L1 '$plabel1' --L2 '$clabel' $parent $child
kdiff3.diff3args=--L1 '$plabel1' --L2 '$clabel' --L3 '$plabel2' $parent1 $child $parent2
kdiff3.dirdiff=True
```

(note `diffargs` + `diff3args` options). From the above source

> the extra keys used by TortoiseHg for visual diff:
>
> ```
> diffargs:  the arguments to use for two-way file comparisons
> diff3args: the arguments to use for three-way file comparisons
> ```
>
> ...
>   If unconfigured, the default value of `diffargs` is ‘$parent $child’.
>   The default value of `diff3args` is “”, indicating **the visual diff tool
>   cannot perform three way comparisons**.

but three way comparisons are the must for mergesets, and your misconfiguration is source of troubles on MacOS's instance of TortoiseHG

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, appreciate your effort. Now it works perfectly after adding only this line under `[merge-tools]`:

`kdiff3.diff3args=--L1 '$plabel1' --L2 '$clabel' --L3 '$plabel2' $parent1 $child $parent2`